# tex-live can't find .sty in texmfhome on lubuntu

Tags: packages

I'm trying to run a `Makefile` that I've already seen running on another computer.
It's path on my machine is `~/metrics/Manuscripts/LRP/Makefile`
It uses my professor's `prof-lang.sty` file which is kept in my `~/texmf/proftex/tex/latex/` folder (`~/texmf` is my `TEXMFHOME`). Upon reading the `Makefile` I saw this it assigns `LOCALTEXMF=../../../proftex/` so I turned that path (`~/proftex`) into a softlink to the original folder.
still, when activating the `Makefile` I always get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `prof-lang.sty' not found
```

so if latex can't find the file in my `TEXMFHOME` not in it's local `texmf`, where should I put it?
I installed `texlive-full`, so I didn't think there's anything more to do in that front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the TeX Directory Structure (TDS) (aka texmf tree) is, that the programs do not have to search the full three. If a font is searched, it is searched below TDS:fonts//, TeX files go below TDS:tex//. (TDS: means the start of the texmf tree, e.g. `~/texmf/`.)

In your case the problem is fixed, if you move `proftex` below `tex/latex`:

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/proftex/
```

and put `prof-lang.sty` there:

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/proftex/prof-lang.sty
```

Details can be found in the [specification](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf).

### `LOCALTEXMF`

If you want to use a `LOCALTEXMF` tree for the project, then again, the files are sorted according to the TDS. Example, assuming the root for the tree is located in `~/proftex/`. Then `LOCALTEXMF` points there:

```
LOCALTEXMF = ~/proftex
```

The file `prof-lang.sty` goes in

```
~/proftex/tex/latex/proftex/prof-lang.sty
```

Important is that the file name data base is updated, when files are added, deleted or moved:

```
texhash ~/proftex
```

or

```
mktexlsr ~/proftex
```

This writes and updates the file `~/proftex/ls-R`.

Comment: thank you for the quick and informative answer!
being unable to change the directory structure that my professor had made, I soft linked the ~/texmf/tex/latex folder to my pofessor's and it worked just fine. does that mean my makefile ignores the LOCALTEXMF directive? or have I misunderstood it's purpose?

Comment: @Nailo If you have the file installed in TEXMFHOME as described, then LaTeX will find the package, before TEXMFLOCAL is searched (the variable for the local tee is called TEXMFLOCAL since some time).